# Elasticsearch - using Update By Query is giving an error on doc_type

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to update multiple documents at once using:

```
    q = {
        "script": {
            "inline": "ctx._source.text.class='contact'",
            "lang": "painless"
        },
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "name": "Contact.txt"
            }
        }
    }

    es.update_by_query(body=q, doc_type='document', index='index_name')
```

If the fieldname 'name' is 'Contact.txt', I want to update it with `'text':{'class':'contact'}`

However I am getting the error

```
TypeError: update_by_query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc_type'
```

The type is document, so I'm confused. I tried removing the arguement and got another error

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, 'script_exception', 'runtime error')
```

Comment: Are you using elastic search 7.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using elastic version 7.x. This no more requires `doc_type` to be specified as mapping types are removed for 7.x.

The following should work:

```
es.update_by_query(body=q, index='index_name')
```